# Elegent argument for the convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n^z}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, holomorphic-functions

I want to prove that
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n^z} \quad (\mathrm{Re}(z) > 1)$$
defines a holomorphic function. Obviously this would be the case if the series
$$ |f(z)| \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{|\cos(n)|}{n} $$
converges, but I'm not sure that is the case.

Comment: I don't know about proving it's holomorphic, but if $\Re(z)>1$ then since $-1 \leq\cos(n)\leq 1$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|cos(n)|}{n^z} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^z} = \zeta(z)$, and so the series absolutely converges everywhere.

Comment: @florence Well sort of, but you can't say exactly what you said because $n^z$ is not positive. (This raises the question: What is $|n^z|$?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Shoot, my bad. It does work for absolute values though; does it easily follow from that that the former series converges?

Comment: @CountIblis : really Morera's theorem is too complicated here, where it is enough to show that $\frac{d^k}{dz^k}f(z) = (-1)^k\sum_n \ln(z)^k n^{-z}$ for $Re(z) > 1$, i.e. $f(z)$ is complex analytic on $Re(z) > 1$ (restricting to $k=1$ being enough if we know that holomorphic $\implies$ analytic)

Comment: @florence Yes, an absolutely convergent series is convergent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By comparison:

$$\biggl\lvert\frac{\cos n}{n^z}\biggr\rvert=O\biggl(\frac1{n^{\operatorname{Re}z}}\biggr),$$
which converges  if $\;\operatorname{Re}z>1$.

Answer (score 0):

No, the series $\sum\frac{|\cos(n)|}{n}$ does not converge. (Loosely speaking, roughly half the terms are as large as $c/n$.)

**Hint:** Saying $f(z)$ is holomorphic in the region $\Re z>1$ is the same as saying that it's holomorphic in the region $\Re z>1+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: ["Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site"](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour), not a hinting site.

Comment: @arney Well MSE should neither be a site that does homework for people. Some homework type of questions come up again and again (like this one) and in these cases a push in the right direction can be appropriate. If you don't show any effort (as you have not done) don't expect to get much back. If you want to know what users say about this issue take a look at meta e.g.: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10589/do-hints-belong-in-answers-or-comments/ - http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4300/why-do-some-answerers-prefer-full-solutions-to-hints-for-homework-and-homework-l

Comment: @Winther http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20000/answering-questions-with-a-hint#comment75763_20000

Comment: @arney That is the opinion of **one** user (and the most extreme one in many respects). I'm not taking sides here, I just wanted to let you know that there are several different opinions on this on this site - and it's the users of this site that defines what this site is supposed to be. Since you are new try to see how things are done, read what people think and then make up your own mind. That is all I wanted to convey.

Comment: @arney ...on second though nevermind. I see that you are not new, but have been on this site for a long time. The comment above is not that relevant in that case. I assumed you were new and though the frontpage was to be taken litterary. Anyway: very nice of you to downvote people wanting to help you.

Comment: @arney Wow. If you like I could tell you where to go to get your money back...

Comment: @Winther "That is the opinion of one user..." Did you read the post from that one user? It seems clear our friend didn't. Cuz it's funny, that one user isn't supporting his position at all - that one user clearly feels that hints are often the Right Thing to Do, and he's complaining that it doesn't work out. Because of inappropriate reactions from the hintee. The irony is just delicious...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think the link OP gives above is to the first comment (by Bookend) and not Will's answer. Anyway, sorry for cluttering up the comment field here.